# Galois representation of an elliptic curve over a function field of char p.

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-representations, function-fields

Let $E/K$ be a non-isotrivial elliptic curve over a function field of characteristic $p$. Let
$$\rho_{E,l}:Gal(K^{sep}/K)\to GL_2(\mathbf{Z}_l)$$
For $l\neq p$, the image of $\rho_{E,l}$ is a $l$-adic Lie group closed in $GL_2(\mathbf{Z}_l)$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1425). What is the situation for $l=p$?

Comment: It depends on whether the curve is supersingular (then there is no $p$-torsion) or ordinary (then the $p$-adic Tate module is a line). The first case is probably impossible (because supersingular elliptic curves are defined over finite fields). Even in the latter case, I wonder whether the $p^n$-torsion isn’t defined on a purely inseparable field extension of the $p$-torsion… yielding a finite image Galois representation.

Comment: Thank you very much! By any chance, would you know some reference about this?

Comment: Thinking a little bit more on this, my suggestion is nonsense – what of ordinary elliptic curves defined over finite fields? I’m afraid that I don’t really know of any (non-standard) reference.